# How can I cut the substring from a string in tcl

Tags: tcl

I have string like `NYMEX UTBPI`. Here I want to fetch the index of white space in middle of NYMEX and UTBPI and then from that index to last index I want to cut the substring. In this case my substring will be `UTBPI`
I'm using below

```
set part1 [substr $line [string index  $line " "] [string index  $line end-1]]
```

I'm getting below error.

```
wrong # args: should be "string index string charIndex"
    while executing
"string index  $line  "
    ("foreach" body line 2)
    invoked from within
"foreach line $pollerName {
set part1 [substr $line [string index  $line  ] [string index  $line end-1]]
puts $part1
puts $line
}"
    (file "Config.tcl" line 9)
```

Can you give me the idea on how can I do some other string manupulation as well. Any good link for this.

Comment: The problem is that `" "` is obviously not a valid character index. Supposedly you wanted to use `string first` (which is for searching), not `string index` (which is for extraction).

Comment: I also wonder what `substr` is supposed to do there? Do you care to elaborate on your intent?

Comment: I'd use `split` or (more likely) `regexp` to do this sort of parsing…

Answer (score 8):

I would just use [string range](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/string.htm#M40) and pass it the index of the whitespace (that you can find using **string first** or whatever).

```
% set s "NYMEX UTBPI"
NYMEX UTBPI
% string range $s 6 end
UTBPI
```

Or using **string first** to dynamically find the whitespace:

```
% set output [string range $s [expr {[string first " " $s] + 1}] end]
UTBPI
```

Comment: in this case we have white space (`" "`) at 6th index so we can do it but suppose we don't know the first word length then? 
so i want to find out the first occurence of white space index then from there to end we can cut.Any suggestion. can we do it dynamically.

Comment: @picnic4u, use [`string first`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/string.htm#M8)

Comment: Or `string last` if you're looking for the last space rather than the first one. But maybe you're sure that there will only be 1 space in the string.

Comment: I've updated the example to show how to use string first. Note that you have to add 1 to the index.

Comment: Why is it `string rang` instead of `string range` in the first example?

Comment: Typo, well spotted! Fixed now.

Answer (score 5):

If processor time isn't a problem, split it into a list and take the 2nd element:

```
set part1 [lindex [split $line] 1]
```

If the string can have an arbitrary number of words,

```
set new [join [lrange [split $line] 1 end]]
```

However, I'd use Donal's suggestion and stick with `string` operations.

Answer (score 1):

I think, the best way to do it in Tcl, is:

```
set s "NYMEX UTBPI"
regexp -indices " " $s index;
puts [lindex $index 0]
```

the variable index will contain the first and the last index of your matching pattern. Here, as you are looking for single char, first and last will be the same, so you can use

```
puts [lindex $index 0]
```

or

```
puts [lindex $index 1]
```

For more info, this is the official doc: http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/regexp.htm#M7